# When Are Texture Atlases Appropriate In SpriteKit?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I've seen that texture atlases are used for animations, but would it be appropriate to use for storing UI elements or items that are unrelated?

Comment: If different textures are going to be rendered into the same scene then it would help to put them into one texture. But, when different images are not rendered into the same scene then it may not be useful since a large memory buffer is needed to contain the entire atlas needs to be held in memory. For animations, rendering one frame after another may not see any advantage by putting different frames into a single atlas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is yes, it can be appropriate. You can put them in a texture atlas if they are related UI elements.

From [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH9-SW15):

**Using Texture Atlases to Collect Related Art Assets**

Art assets stored in your app bundle aren’t always unrelated images. Sometimes they are collections of images that are being used together for the same sprite. For example, here are a few common collections of art assets:

- Animation frames for a character
- Terrain tiles used to create a game level or puzzle
- Images used for user interface controls, such as buttons, switches,
  and sliders

If each texture is treated as a separate object, then Sprite Kit and the graphics hardware must work harder to render scenes—and your game’s performance might suffer. Specifically, Sprite Kit must make at least one drawing pass per texture. To avoid making multiple drawing passes, Sprite Kit uses texture atlases to collect related images together. You specify which assets should be collected together, and Xcode builds a texture atlas automatically. Then, when your game loads the texture atlas, Sprite Kit manages all the images inside the atlas as if they were a single texture. You continue to use SKTexture objects to access the elements contained in the atlas.